# Comparing the result of a subquery with LIKE

Tags: mysql, subquery, like

I need to find all the movies that have all of its actors' names to start with an A and have a 60.000.000 or more of gross. I have this but is not working

```
SELECT title, imdb_score
FROM Movie AS m    
WHERE "A%" = ALL(SELECT name 
                FROM Actor_Movie AS am, Person AS p, Actor AS a 
                WHERE m.id_movie = am.id_movie 
                      AND a.id_actor = am.id_actor 
                      AND a.id_actor = p.id_person) 
                      AND gross > 60000000 
order by imdb_score DESC;
```

Comment: "Alice" and "Bob" -- is this excluded by "all of its actors' names to start with an A"?  Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should use inner joins instead of comma

I search in the subquery for all movieids thta have actors that start with A

```
SELECT title, imdb_score
FROM Movie AS m    
WHERE id_movie IN (SELECT id_movie
                   FROM Actor_Movie AS am 
                        INNER JOIN Actor AS a  ON a.id_actor = am.id_actor
                        INNER JOIN  Person AS p ON a.id_actor = p.id_person
                    WHERE name LIKE 'A%')
       AND gross > 60000000 
order by imdb_score DESC;
```

The IN Clause don't support huge numbers of elements, so that you have to switch to another inner join like this

```
SELECT title, imdb_score
FROM Movie AS m  INNER JOIN (SELECT id_movie
                   FROM Actor_Movie AS am 
                        INNER JOIN Actor AS a  ON a.id_actor = am.id_actor
                        INNER JOIN  Person AS p ON a.id_actor = p.id_person
                    WHERE name LIKE 'A%') t1 ON m.id_movie = t1.id_movie
WHERE  gross > 60000000 
order by imdb_score DESC;
```

Comment: *so that you have to switch to another inner join like this* Do the next logical step - remove subquery at all.

Comment: `IN ( SELECT ... )` can handle arbitrarily many elements.  `IN ( 11,22,33,... )` can handle at least 100K elements, but there are a couple of things that will probably say there is a limit.